# How can I fix the rotation for this hand?

Tags: bones, transform-orientation

I'm making the rigging for a hand, but for some reason after I do the Ctrl+N, choose the Global +X. Not all of my bones stay on the same orientation, how can I fix this?

[image]

I want all of the Z axis to point to the same direction.

Comment: Try a different global axis option.  If that's a top-down view, recalculate to global -Z.

Answer (score 0):

you have to rotate them in edit mode by pressing R + the axis to rotate (you are wanting to align the bone rotations so you have to select if i am not mistaking the Y axis must be) and rotate the by a value of 90  or -90. ensure that the armature its not assigned to a mesh because it may get really bad bug in your mesh if you are editting it (the armature) with it, so you have to clear the parent and when you are done fixing it parent it again.

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot, it seems that the Y axis of your bones are almost along the global X axis. Since the *Recalculate Roll* operator only modifies the roll (points the Z axis of the selected bones towards the selected direction), it's just not able to find a consistent roll for all bones.

If you want the Z axis of the bones to point down, you need to select **global -Z axis** as Nathan pointed out in the comments.